# How to Trigger Marker events on google map when clicking on li element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am super stuck here, I have looked into other questions on this topic but can not seem to find the answer. I am trying to get get the markers on the google map to display the info window when the corresponding item on the list is clicked, but have no idea how to get it done. here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

var  AllPlaces = [
  {
    "name" : "Pizza",
    "lat": "40.7589",
    "lng":"-73.9851",
  },

  {
    "name" : "Cookies",
    "lat": "40.7690",
    "lng":"-73.9952",
  }
]

class MapContainer extends Component {
state = {
showingInfoWindow: false,
activeMarker: {},
selectedPlace: {},
query:'',
markerObjects:[]
};



onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
console.log(marker);
this.setState({
  selectedPlace: props,
  activeMarker: marker,
  showingInfoWindow: true
});
}

onLiClick = (markers) =>{
//AllPlaces.foreach(
  //if(markers.target.innerHTML === )
//google.maps.event.trigger(marker,'click')) This is where I am trying to create the function for when the Li item is clicked
}


onMapClicked = (props) => {
if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
  this.setState({
    showingInfoWindow: false,
    activeMarker: null
  })
}
}


CreateInputField = () => {
return <input
placeholder = "Search Nearby Places"
/>
}

findPlaces = () => {
return(
  <ol className='Places'>
    {AllPlaces.map((arrayItem, index)=>
      <li
      key = {index}
      className='Place'
      //onClick={() => {this.onLiClick}}
      >{arrayItem.name}</li>
    )}
  </ol>
)
};

render() {
return (
  <div className = 'map-container' style={{marginleft:'250px'}}>
    <div>
      <div className = 'sideMenu'>
        <div className = 'List'>
          <h1 className = 'title'> Places to Eat </h1>
            {this.CreateInputField()}
        </div>
        <div className = 'PlaceList'>
          {this.findPlaces()}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}
      initialCenter = {{lat:40.7589, lng:-73.9851}}
      onClick={this.onMapClicked}>
      <Marker
        onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
        title = {AllPlaces[0].name}
        name={AllPlaces[0].name}
        position = {{lat:AllPlaces[0].lat,lng:AllPlaces[0].lng}}/>
      <Marker
        onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
        title = {AllPlaces[1].name}
        name={AllPlaces[1].name}
        position = {{lat:AllPlaces[1].lat,lng:AllPlaces[1].lng}}/>
      <InfoWindow
        onOpen={this.windowHasOpened}
        onClose={this.windowHasClosed}
        marker={this.state.activeMarker}
        visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
        <div>
          <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
        </div>
      </InfoWindow>
    </Map>
  </div>
  );
}
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
apiKey: 'AIzaSyC21SntdNn1vCb5VOAujCPIM7a9p5XkvRs'
})(MapContainer)
```

So far I have tried to write if statements to compare the innerHTML and the name on the marker but have not found a way to do this successfully if it can be done at all, im not sure. I have tried to create an array of all the markers but also have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a `ref` on each marker so that way you can access it from your functions.

Something like this should work. I'm setting a ref for each marker on its marker property which is the same marker object the `InfoWindow` expects. Then, I'm just accessing it on that Locations array index.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from 'google-maps-react';

var  AllPlaces = [
  {
    "name" : "Pizza",
    "lat": "40.7589",
    "lng":"-73.9851",
  },

  {
    "name" : "Cookies",
    "lat": "40.7690",
    "lng":"-73.9952",
  }
]

class MapContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    showingInfoWindow: false,
    activeMarker: {},
    selectedPlace: {},
    query:'',
  };

  markers = []

  onMarkerClick = (props, marker, e) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedPlace: props,
      activeMarker: marker,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });
  }

  onLiClick = (i) =>{
    this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: true,
        activeMarker: this.markers[i],
        selectedPlace: AllPlaces[i]
    })
  }


  onMapClicked = (props) => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow) {
      this.setState({
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: null
      })
    }
  }


  CreateInputField = () => (
    <input
      placeholder = "Search Nearby Places"
    />
  )

  findPlaces = () => (
    <ol className='Places'>
      {AllPlaces.map((arrayItem, index)=>
        <li
        key = {index}
        className='Place'
        onClick={() => {this.onLiClick(index)}}
        >{arrayItem.name}</li>
      )}
    </ol>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <div className = 'map-container' style={{marginleft:'250px'}}>
        <div>
          <div className = 'sideMenu'>
            <div className = 'List'>
              <h1 className = 'title'> Places to Eat </h1>
                {this.CreateInputField()}
            </div>
            <div className = 'PlaceList'>
              {this.findPlaces()}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={14}
          initialCenter = {{lat:40.7589, lng:-73.9851}}
          onClick={this.onMapClicked}>
          {AllPlaces.map((marker, i) => 
              <Marker
              ref={(e) => {if (e) this.markers[i] = e.marker}}
              onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
              title = {marker.name}
              name={marker.name}
              position = {{lat:marker.lat,lng:marker.lng}}
              />
          )}
          <InfoWindow
            onOpen={this.windowHasOpened}
            onClose={this.windowHasClosed}
            marker={this.state.activeMarker}
            visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}>
            <div>
              <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
            </div>
          </InfoWindow>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: 'AIzaSyC21SntdNn1vCb5VOAujCPIM7a9p5XkvRs'
})(MapContainer)
```

Comment: That you this was exactly what I needed it makes so much sense now!!!!!

Comment: @HyunjinKim no problem! Could you mark my response as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark? It's to the left of my response just under the upvote/downvote arrows. Thanks :)